# Problem in manifest application tag when we giveandroid:name="" app crash

Tags: java, android

I used firebase offline capability in my app. It will add name tag in manifest file. When I add name tag the app will crash. I search it but no solution can be found.

**Here is the manifest code**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fsd.finalyearproject.nut.rozgar.rozgar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false"/>
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".Rozgar_Offline">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.VerifyNumberActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.UserProfileActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.AgreeTermsAndConditionsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <!-- for image crop but it is optional -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.GetUserDetailOnceTimeAfterSignUpActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.JobDonorsHomeActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.JobDonorsSelectCatageoryActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.JobDonorsSelectTitleDescriptionActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.AllJobsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.JobDetailActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.FavouriteJobsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.ChatActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activites.AllChatsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />

        <service
            android:name=".Services.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**java file Rozgar_Offline**

```java
    public class Rozgar_Offline extends Application {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            //for text
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

                //for images
                Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
                builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                Picasso built = builder.build();
                built.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
                built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
                Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
            }

        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);
            MultiDex.install(this);
        }
    }
```

If any one has a solution or knows about this problem please tell me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: check the logcat and see the crash stacktrace to know what is the problem

Comment: @Muhammad Please post the crash you are getting.

Comment: why are you giving dot inside app name?  .Rozgar_Offline  why do you need dot ?

Comment: @GaneshGudghe dot works as relative path, which means *application_package_name*.Rozgar_Offline

Comment: Post your crash detail.

Comment: Post you package structure. Need to verify the . usage